# How can i disable line level "Make Copy" Button in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am new to netsuite
I want to disable line level "Make Copy" Button when sales order is open in edit type.
i read in netsuite help but didnt get the right way to do.

Comment: Do you mean `copy previous` button in lineitem ?

Comment: No.  Make Copy button in lineitem. suppose we edit sales order record and select existing item row then it is visible with OK , CANCEL REMOVE & INSERT button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the button table completely, then you can write a client script like below. On page load it will hide your button.

```
function clientPageInit(type){
       if(type == 'edit'){
           setFieldAndLabelVisibility("tbl_item_copy", false);
       }
    }
```

Note: You'll lose the `Copy Previous` button also as we're hiding the parent table i.e `tbl_item_copy`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you cannot. Try client script on line init and check type, if type == copy, do nothing or give alert message and return.

Comment: thanks for answer.. But you mean to say i can use line init and check type=='item' then do nothing.. i done as you said but then we cant able to edit existing item rows..